# Configure CruiseControl.NET with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, cruisecontrol.net

The project I currently work on uses CruiseControl.NET 1.8.4.0 and I want to integrate it with SonarQube. This is the only information I found about this [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Continuous+Integration#ContinuousIntegration-CruiseControl) and I could not make it work.
Could someone please enlighten me how can this be achieved.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on the details of the failure.

Comment: Your are linking to an old SonarQube documentation page. Why not using SonarQube 5.6.6?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your issue including what errors you met? And I think maybe you could refer to this document: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about sonarqube but I know a lot about cruisecontrol. Cruisecontrol.net is just a queue that runs tasks. All the actual work in the tasks is done by things other than ccnet for example msbuild, nant, etc. So I'm guessing your situation is similar where ccnet is the outer queue which runs tasks and sonarqube needs to be one of those tasks ccnet runs.

I don't know how sonarqube runs but maybe it can be run through the exec task in ccnet. This allows ccnet to run any executable assuming sonarqube is an executable.

[ccnet exec task](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task)

The docs link you posted looks like it's running something on linux. Also, the "CruiseControl" the doc page references may very well be the Java Cruisecontrol([Java CruiseControl (runs on linux)](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/download.html))

The first thing to answer is, are you really dealing with cruisecontrol.net? Or is it actually java cruisecontrol for linux? They are different tools although they share the same origin.